# i have already developed an app in java how do i open it in xcode simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

My team has developed a big social networking app. Now i want to publish it to app store. But the app is not written in Objective C. What is the way to get it published in app store? Or least how can i open in in Xcode simulator for testing and enhancement?

Comment: What tool did you use to developer the java App in? iOS is nto able to run java apps thus you code will need to be converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Sorry.

I recently worked on an app for iOS and Android launch and we settled for parallel development.

Your Java code is incompatible with iOS and Xcode has no process to convert it to Obj-c.
The only options for cross-platform development that I am aware of are:

1) Heavy use of c/c++ based libraries; these can be utilised in both Android applications and iOS applications (this is what we used). But the entire front end of the apps must be re-implemented.

2) A cross-platform framework such as PhoneGap or Appcelerator, but this would require significant redevelopment from your current code-base.

3) A 'translator' such as the one Breno Gazzola suggested (another option is XMLVM) but these only do some of the work for you, and they're far from perfect.

It's very hard to judge without knowing your code, but if I were you I'd look at combining options 1 and 3 as much as possible, but budget for a complete re-write.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you created an app in android and now want to port it to iOS. Unfortunately Xcode isn't able to transform Java to Objective-C and iOS cannot run Java apps, so you will not be able yo submit your app as-is to the App Store.

You will have to do it the hard way and rewrite the entire app in Objective-C. Luckily Google recently launched a translator that might help with part of the work: http://google-opensource.blogspot.com.br/2012/09/j2objc-java-to-ios-objective-c.html